# How to deal with the following scenario in Oauth2?

Tags: oauth-2.0

Suppose I have the APIs as below:

```
/app/user_info
/app/car_info
```

The system is able to create different branches which is something like: department, subsidiary, in our system it is branch school

Assume we have :

```
BranchA
BranchB
```

The APIs is branch wise, It will show the data according to the current branch id which is selected by the current logined user who switch the different branch in the front-end.

Now, we have a User who is able to access all the APIs in BranchA.
In the meanwhile, The User has a limited permissions to access APIs in the BranchB (Suppose User can only access /app/user_info).

```
1 User - BranchA -  /app/user_info,app/car_info
2 User - BranchB -  /app/user_info
```

So how to cope with the similar scenario?
Each branch will correspond to the different access token and the scope is different too. So Do I need to assign multiple token to the user in one authorization? It is not possible according to OAUTH2.
To resolve this, I think I need to assign a new access token & refresh token when user switch to the diffrent branch ? But how to assign a new token without user re-login, this is the question I want to ask. I have almost no experience of oauth2 about this situation.

Answer (score 1):

OAuth will not give you a solution for domain specific authorization.

You typically will instead need to manage it in your application logic, something like this:

- Keep OAuth logins focused on identifying the user, which will result in an access token containing the user id
- In your application data, map users or roles to allowed branches
- Design your API to include branch ids
- When your API receives a request, look up the user from the token and verify that the logged in user has access to the branch

As an example:

- Get a list of branches from /branches which will return those for the user in the token
- Get data for a branch from /branches/({id}/car_info - which will return a 403 forbidden response if the user in the token does not have access to the requested branch

Comment: The rule that the client accesss the APIs should be better defined in the access token scope I think, So If a user switch the branch to another in  the front-end , It is better making another qualified access token? Is this a better choose?

Eg: /api/switch-branch/branchId/ . in this api, the server will make a Client Credentials Grant oauth access to oauth provider to fetch the new access token and refresh token for the user?

Comment: I would use scopes at a high level, but you're likely to struggle to have a separate scope per branch and manage changes over time if there are a large number of branches. Client Credentials may work for you, if you are initiating it from a back end that has the client secret - but there will be no user id for this type of token.

Comment: Good Day Gary Archer, Thx your suggestion. In fact each person will have several branches, not so much. and the scopes are still high level, because all the scopes in the different branch are some,  the only difference is: some user in the specific branch has less scope items. It seems the method I thought is practicable ? But the user id could not be obtained in the token might be the biggest problem. Could you give me some idea for it ?

Comment: No magic solution - understand the limitations of each OAuth flow and design accordingly. You need an original way to identify the user - generally based on login. In your example 'switch branch' is an API call and APIs do not issue tokens. The only way to get a new token is via an OAuth flow, and none of them can be customised in this way.

Comment: You may be able to do conditional issuing of tokens via a double hop : UI calls back end which uses client credentials flow which then calls target API and supplies the user id via a REST parameter - usually a path segment.

Comment: Generally I recommend this type of approach where the concerns are separated and easy to change - this may be more than you want to deal with though [my blog article]( https://authguidance.com/2017/10/03/api-tokens-claims/) describes

Comment: Hi Gary Archer, the user id is appended in the path might cause the secure risk, The api dont known which user id is real. Does the JWT can help this, as far as I known It allows to make a customized token content

Comment: The solution you wrote in Blog is a good design, I think I will consider that. And seems the scope will be no useful under the solution.

Comment: Cool - user IDs in paths should only ever be used for API operations called only by a trusted back end component - they would not be secure if called from a public UI - as you pointed out. Looking up branch details after login feels best to me - and details can be cached if needed. My [Demo UIs](https://authguidance.com/home/code-samples-quickstart) are very similar - if you imagine the companies list represents the user's branches.